# SVN: set all files marked with "!" to "D"?

Tags: svn, repository

long story short, a mistake was made and now I have at least one hundred files throughout dozens of folders that need to be removed from my repository.

Right now they're all marked as "!" in *svn status* and I'd like to remove them without manually typing in *svn remove blahblah*.

Is there a quick way to do this?

Comment: Ah, sorry. It's OSX, but the answer below worked out.

Comment: Applications should not allow humans to multiply their errors by 10000 :P Oh, the horrors I've had when I thought a quick "replace all" would solve my refactoring issues :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is pretty easy to do with a little shell-scripting-foo.

```
svn status | grep "^\!" | awk '{print $2}' | xargs svn del
```

Here's a breakdown, as requested:

- The output of `svn status` is piped to `grep`
- `grep` pipes every line that starts with a `!` (The `^` in a regex means beginning of line, and the '\' is necessary to escape the special meaning of `!`)
- `awk` then takes the second "argument" (so to speak.. this is the path of the file) from `grep` and pipes only it to...
- `xargs` which is simply a utility for building an executing shell commands from standard input, which generates and runs the command `svn del your/file/here`

You can also use variations on this line to do all sorts of handy things with `svn`, like recursively adding files to the repo:

```
svn status | grep "^\?" | awk '{print $2}' | xargs svn add
```

Also, I just remembered, and wanted to point out that this will not work if you have spaces in your path or filenames. I always forget about that, because I never, ever do. If you have  spaces in your paths/filenames, use the following variation on the first example:

```
svn status | grep "^\!" | sed -e 's/? *//' | sed -e 's/ /\\ /g' | xargs svn del
```

(There's probably a more graceful way to do that, so feel free to chime in). In this one, the first `sed` takes the first whitespace character, and any (if any) spaces that follow it, and removes them (basically a trim). Then the second call to `sed` replaces any remaining spaces with `\`, which is an escaped space, as far as the shell is concerned. Come to think of it, you could probably just wrap it with quotes...

Comment: If you don't want to remove the file locally, don't forget the --keep-local argument.

Comment: Thanks. I'm still kind of new to the shell, so I want to make sure I understand what this line is doing.

The output of svn status is being used as a file for grep, which searches for ! (what does the ^ do?). I'm guessing $2 refers to the 2nd group of non-whitespace characters which is put into svn del?

Is that right?

Comment: Ya, that sounds right.  "^" matches with the the beginning of the line and differentiates between strings like ".....!..." and "!......"